# Obtain a specific string from aks

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics

I would like to know if it's possbile with Azure Log Analytics, to get a special string inside a container.
I want to check the presence of a specific file in my AKS.

Is there a solution to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the OMS Agent only fetches STDOUT & STDERR of your pods. So you can print the presence of the file to STDOUT and then you are able to query it with Azure Log Analytics.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response. Do you have an idea of query to apply ?

Comment: You have a lot of examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-log-query